# How can I do user research with a database of 100,000 users?

Tags: user-research, users

How could I start doing user research with such a large database?

The techniques that I want to occupy are:

- Focus Group
- Interviews
- Contextual Immersion

My doubt is how to start working with a large volume of users.

Comment: Is this a database of potential participants or already gathered data?

Comment: already gathered data...

Comment: What to do with it depends on the data and your objectives. Before it was collected, someone should have had some idea of what types of statistics would be appropriate. If you want to run scenarios, you can process random subsets. It shouldn't be a problem for a computer.

Comment: Could you provide some further information on what data was collected about the users? Are you planning to identify a subset (representative samples) of users to study with the listed techniques?

Answer (score 2):

You already seem to have the methods in mind and ordered too. But to start with may be do a Cohort Analysis and create sensible groups based on probably job-title, country or another factor considering what is available in the data (assuming you already have some data on the users). From thereon, you may create a focus group with people representing different cohorts and proceed as planned towards Contextual Immersion. There may be multiple focus groups based on location may be (just an example) - two focus groups in two different countries.

Comment: I can only think of two possible cases - either it is consumer data or it is an enterprise product with employee data available. Just guessing. But it will help if you could add a bit more detail there.

Comment: I'm collecting more data in the company, patience please!

Comment: we have a platform with 90,000 active users, of those users ...

7,600 have registered more than 5 times

19,000 more than two.

35,000 more than one.